# What's the best way to implement localization for an existing ASPNET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I need to translate an existing ASPNET MVC application to multiple languages. I created a Resources folder and I was planning on adding resource files (resx), moving all the text to said resource files and referencing them in the views and models where needed.

Is this a good approach? If it is, should I make one resource file per controller? A global one with everything?

I imagine having one resource file per controller makes it easier to maintain, but adding a new translation would mean creating hundreds of new files.

On the other hand, having everything in one file might have a negative effect performance-wise.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add resource files with different cultures. Set the access modifiers in resource file to public.

Resource file will have name and value field. In name field define key and in value column provide the value in your language.

And use the key in razor pages and Custom messages in ur programs.

(Note that, for all resource files, the key will be same and the value will be change with the language)